# Null Pointer Exception when creating a 2D picker

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a 2D picker on an android wear app using GridPager but keep running into a very odd error. I have tried redoing everything and rebuilding but nothing seems to work.

My main class is as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView mTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final GridViewPager pager = (GridViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(new GridPagerAdapter(this, getFragmentManager()));
    }
}
```

I am trying to follow the example found here:
    https://github.com/mauimauer/AndroidWearable-Samples/blob/master/GridViewPager/Wearable/src/main/java/com/example/android/wearable/gridviewpager/MainActivity.java

I keep getting a NullPointerException on the lne pager.setAdapter(...);

I can share my GridPagerAdapter file if needed.

Comment: Sounds like the activity_main layout (xml) doesn't contain the GridViewPager named "pager". Check your xml files (maybe you have several layouts?)

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

doesn't have the ID of pager. 

setContentView(R.layout.round_activity_main);

does have it. Thanks for catching my stupid errors!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the activity_main layout (xml) doesn't contain the `GridViewPager` named "`pager`". Check your xml files